# Does CAS conflict with volatile

Tags: java, volatile

Now that cas has volatile read and write semantics, why should volatile be combined to implement synchronized code blocks?
For example, the shared variables of all classes under the java.util.concurrent.atomic package will be modified with volatile.
`public class AtomicInteger extends Number implements java.io.Serializable { private volatile int value; }`

Comment: I don't get your question. volatile reads/writes/cas is great if you just need to synchronize on a single field. But if you need more than 1 field or blocking, you need a lock (synchronized code blocks).

Comment: Cas doesn't conflict with volatile; a volatile load and store is an atomic operation just as a read modify write (cas).